# How to get (or generate) link to untrash a post?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom admin page on a Wordpress that allows showing the posts in a certain required way.

Each post is represented as a card that includes a trash icon to send the post to the trash. It's easy with:

```
<?php $trash_link = get_delete_post_link( $id ); ?>
<a href="<?= $trash_link ?>"><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span></a>
```

I'd like to replace this icon/link for a restore one when I'm currently viewing my trashed posts but I cannot figure out how to get the link since it doesn't seem to exist a `get_undelete_post_link()` or `get_untrash_post_link()`.

Trash links look like:
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=8459&action=trash&_wpnonce=937a7ccb5d

While untrash links look like:
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=8459&action=untrash&_wpnonce=53facd85e3

So I tried:

```
<?php
$trash_link = get_delete_post_link( $id );
if ( $post->post_status == 'trash' ):
    $restore_link = str_replace( 'trash', 'untrash', $trash_link );
endif;
```

That gives an apparently correct link but, of course, it doesn't work since nonce doesn't verify.

I guess I could build my own system using `wp_create_nonce()` and `wp_untrash_post()`, but is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an easy way looking at how this is done in Wordpress' core.

They use [`wp_nonce_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url):

> Retrieve URL with nonce added to URL query. The returned result is escaped for display.

So,

```
<?php
$post_id = $post->ID;
$restore_link = wp_nonce_url(
    "post.php?action=untrash&amp;post=$post_id",
    "untrash-post_$post_id"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the simple logic to generate untrash link

```
 <?php
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $restore_link = wp_nonce_url(admin_url("post.php?action=untrash&post=$post_id"),"untrash-post_$post_id");
```